# horizontal centering

Tags: css, center

here is the page : http://aevm.ca/fond2.html

when i use this css : 
it's left align and top at zero

```
#center {
    height: 100%;
    width: 960px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FF0;
    top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    }
```

when i use this css : 
it's center align and top at 10-20 pixel (WHY?)

```
#center {
        height: 100%;
        width: 960px;
        position: relative; (the only difference)
        background-color: #FF0;
        top: 0px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        }
```

How i can get top position and horizontal center ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: relative` on `#center`.

This is Line 16 of your source code:

```
<script src="jquery.backstretch.min.js" .. ></script><br>
```

Get rid of the *sneaky* `<br>` :D

Answer (score 0):

If position is `relative` you must type `margin-top:0;` Try this;

```
#center {
        height: 100%;
        width: 960px;
        position: relative; (the only difference)
        background-color: #FF0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }
```